# assign values to arrays with eval and symbols in Julia

Tags: arrays, for-loop, julia, eval, symbols

I have a dictionary that has 3 key, each key has arbitrary 2d arrays. And I want to assign each of these values(2d arrays) to newly created arrays. So I wrote this :

```
levels = (:easy, :medium, :hard)
easy = []; medium = []; hard = [];
curriculum = Dict((k=>rand(3,3) for k in levels)...); # dictionary with 3 keys - each key is a symbol
for level in levels
    eval(level) = curriculum[level]
end
```

There is no problem during execution but when I check the easy, medium or hard arrays after, there are no matrices inside.

What is the proper way of doing this? 
B.R.

**(edited)**

What I understand is that during the loop iteration eval(level) behaves like local binding. Thus, at the end of the iteration it does not remember anything. But why? And how to convert to global again ?

Comment: When pasting code it is better to make it run and produce the (possibly bad) output. In this case, replacing the `load` with `curriculum = Dict((k=>rand(3,3) for k in levels)...)` would help potential answerers

Comment: @DanGetz Sorry, you're right. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no problem during execution but when I check the easy, medium or hard arrays after, there are no matrices inside.
>
> What I understand is that during the loop iteration eval(level) behaves like local binding. Thus, at the end of the iteration it does not remember anything. But why? And how to convert to global again ?

The problem is that you are defining and then redefining an `eval` function in each iteration inside the `for` loop, instead of doing assignments as you believe.

---

```rb
easy = []; medium = []; hard = []
```

1.- There is no need to predefine this variables.

---

```rb
eval(level) = curriculum[level]
```

2.- **Warning: This is being interpreted as a short style function definition!**

```rb
julia> eval(level) = curriculum[level]
eval (generic function with 1 method)
```

---

```rb
julia> levels = :easy, :medium, :hard
(:easy, :medium, :hard)

julia> curriculum = Dict((k => rand(3, 3) for k in levels)...)
Dict{Symbol,Array{Float64,2}} with 3 entries:
  :medium => [0.230877 0.244128 0.205712; 0.649405 0.887568 0.957849; 0.245076 0.476088 0.160561]
  :hard   => [0.0424943 0.157261 0.798607; 0.590535 0.78125 0.704322; 0.555827 0.675355 0.74026]
  :easy   => [0.715595 0.914093 0.517973; 0.750787 0.489784 0.491666; 0.1966 0.133281 0.249144]

julia> for level in levels
           @eval $level = curriculum[$(Meta.quot(level))]
       end

julia> easy
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.715595  0.914093  0.517973
 0.750787  0.489784  0.491666
 0.1966    0.133281  0.249144
```

3.- Inside the `for` loop, in the first iteration, `$level` is interpreted as the `easy` variable identifier, while `$(Meta.quot(level))` is interpreted as the symbol `:easy`, for which the extra level of *quoting* is needed.

```rb
julia> Meta.quot(:foo)   
:(:foo)                  
                     
julia> Expr(:quote, :foo)
:(:foo)
```

Comment: Nice! :) Where did you find that info pls?

Comment: Chatting a lot with Fengyang Wang (meta hero) mostly AKA `TotalVerb` back in the not so old good days (thank you so much Feng! :D ) and fiddling lots more on my own. You could add an example of this to the manual if you like.

Comment: @Liso there were more metaprogramming examples at the now shut down [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816195537/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/julia-lang/1945/metaprogramming#t=201708161955375736698), maybe they are worth rescuing?

Comment: Thanks to both of you! :) Maybe good new days are coming... ;)

Comment: Feel free to also join the new [Stack Overflow JuliaLang chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162786/julialang) if you like! :D

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** there is a better way as pointed out in the accepted answer and comment by Ismael. Namely that:

> global level = level is not necessary, see my answer, the issue is
>   that if you want to interpolate a symbol into an expression as a
>   symbol instead of as an identifier, then you need to wrap the symbol
>   into another quote expression.

---

**Warning:** this is (almost certainly) **not** the best way of setting out to accomplish whatever you want to do. Metaprogramming in julia is super powerful and useful but you should very rarely need to use `eval`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/). If you ask another question with the details of your end-goal you might get a better answer :)

Nonetheless:

If you want to do the assignment this way you'll have to create an Expression `Expr` that assigns the matrix object to the variable with the name you want. But because *`eval` always executes the statement in the global scope* you'll need to make the variable you want to use available in the global scope.

```
 for level in levels
     global level = level
     eval(:($level = curriculum[level]))
 end
```

or using the @eval macro:

```
for level in levels
     global level = level
     @eval $level = curriculum[level]
 end
```

Comment: `global level = level` is not necessary, see my answer, the issue is that if you want to interpolate a symbol into an expression **as a symbol** instead of **as an identifier**, then you need to wrap the symbol into another *quote* expression.